How to set up clangd with kickstart.nvim
I followed these instructions:
https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim
https://youtu.be/m8C0Cq9Uv9o?feature=shared
I am using Windows with gcc. And I am using Microsoft Terminal (cmd) (available on Microsoft Store) as my terminal.
Almost everything is working well, except for the clangd LSP.
Just uncommenting clangd={} and installing it via mason in the next bootup, doesn't tell clangd where are the library files and it fails to recognize <iostrem> or <bits\stdc++.h>.
And I am not able to figure out what is the right way to set this is up in these constraints in windows.
If anyone has earlier set this up with lazy.nvim with lua in windows before, any help would be great. I could work with WSL but I wanted to keep it to native windows to edit the windows files too seamlessly.
Here is the relevant code in init.lua from the kickstart.nvim project:
      local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
      capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', capabilities, require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities())

      -- Enable the following language servers
      --  Feel free to add/remove any LSPs that you want here. They will automatically be installed.
      --
      --  Add any additional override configuration in the following tables. Available keys are:
      --  - cmd (table): Override the default command used to start the server
      --  - filetypes (table): Override the default list of associated filetypes for the server
      --  - capabilities (table): Override fields in capabilities. Can be used to disable certain LSP features.
      --  - settings (table): Override the default settings passed when initializing the server.
      --        For example, to see the options for `lua_ls`, you could go to: https://luals.github.io/wiki/settings/
      local servers = {
        clangd = {},
        -- gopls = {},
        pyright = {},
        -- rust_analyzer = {},
        -- ... etc. See `:help lspconfig-all` for a list of all the pre-configured LSPs
        --
        -- Some languages (like typescript) have entire language plugins that can be useful:
        --    https://github.com/pmizio/typescript-tools.nvim
        --
        -- But for many setups, the LSP (`ts_ls`) will work just fine
        -- ts_ls = {},
        --

        lua_ls = {
          -- cmd = {...},
          -- filetypes = { ...},
          -- capabilities = {},
          settings = {
            Lua = {
              completion = {
                callSnippet = 'Replace',
              },
              -- You can toggle below to ignore Lua_LS's noisy `missing-fields` warnings
              -- diagnostics = { disable = { 'missing-fields' } },
            },
          },
        },
      }

      -- Ensure the servers and tools above are installed
      --  To check the current status of installed tools and/or manually install
      --  other tools, you can run
      --    :Mason
      --
      --  You can press `g?` for help in this menu.
      require('mason').setup()

      -- You can add other tools here that you want Mason to install
      -- for you, so that they are available from within Neovim.
      local ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers or {})
      vim.list_extend(ensure_installed, {
        'stylua', -- Used to format Lua code
      })
      require('mason-tool-installer').setup { ensure_installed = ensure_installed }

      require('mason-lspconfig').setup {
        handlers = {
          function(server_name)
            local server = servers[server_name] or {}
            -- This handles overriding only values explicitly passed
            -- by the server configuration above. Useful when disabling
            -- certain features of an LSP (for example, turning off formatting for ts_ls)
            server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
            require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
          end,
        },
      }
    end,
  },

I tried adding the path to the required lib files with
set CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0;C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0\include;C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0\include\c++;C:\ProgramData\mingw64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0\include\c++\x86_64-w64-mingw32

But I was receiving various errors like: Error Image

I was able to solve it by adding mingw as the compiler in compile flags in the clangd config.yaml file.
Here is a the detailed medium post I made:
https://medium.com/@adarshroy.formal/setting-up-neovim-on-windows-a-beginner-friendly-no-nonsense-guide-with-cpp-clangd-without-wsl-f792117466a0
